# How to get custom variables when using a custom Email Transport with CakePHP 4, for sending bulk mails with Postmark

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x, postmark

I want to send bulk mail (newsletters) with the Postmark Batch API. Postmark Batch API requires me to combine up to 500 mails per request.

Therefor I have created an custom `NewslettersTransport.php` which is handeling the API call and setting up the batch request. So far so good.

The content of the mails should be personalized. I am looking for a way to do this inside this Transport method, but I can't access my ViewVars set in `NewsletterMailer.php`

I'm searching for a different logic or a way to access the ViewVars / customize the message body.

```
// NewsletterMailer.php

return $this
    ->setEmailFormat('html')
    ->setTo($subscribers->all()->toArray())
    ->setFrom([$newsletter->sender => $company->companyname])
    ->setSubject($newsletter->name)
    ->setProfile('newsletter')
    ->setViewVars([
        'company' => $company
    ])
    ->viewBuilder()
    ->setTemplate('newsletter_mail')
    ->setLayout('default');
```

Comment: Why do you want to do customization in the transport? AFAICT postmark expects complete email bodies, no placeholders or something like that, ie you'd just use the variables in your email templates!?

Comment: I didn't but I could not find the right solution. Thats why I was looking for different logic. But in the meanwhile I found the documentation to do it better: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-emails-without-using-mailer

`$transport = new \Cake\Mailer\Transport\MailTransport();
$result = $transport->sendBatch($messages);`